# Как правильно версионировать входные данные?

Tags: архитектура, проектирование, версионирование

Есть система из нескольких модулей.
Основная задача - получить набор XML файлов, проверить их и загрузить в базу.

Последовательность такая:

- Получаем XML
- Проверяем по XSD
- Проверяем каждую ноду набором скриптов
- Сериализуем и загружаем в базу

Если один из пунктов вернул ошибку, заворачиваем процесс.
Все работает, все хорошо.

Вот только возникла необходимость изменить входные данные сохранив при этом обратную совместимость.
Для этого в XML есть тэг с версией.

Вроде ситуация рядовая - добавить пару новых схем, скриптов и обработчик сериализации.
Все усложняется тем, что скриптов под сотню (и будет больше) и версии будут выходить регулярно.
Так же в одной версии скрипт проверяет ноду одним способом, в другой другим.

Какие есть best practises на эту тему?
Требования к результату такие:

- В СУБД всегда должна быть только последняя версия схемы, но все данные за все время. Хранить предыдущие схемы нет надобности, а данные надо каждый раз адаптировать.
- Совместимость нужна только между новой и предыдущей версией файлов. Старьё тянуть не надо.
- Изменения могут быть очень глобальными и скрипты могут сильно отличаться.

Как такое лучше реализовать?

Основной затык для меня - это скрипты. Ничего лучше чем вписать в каждый скрипт поддержку версий не придумал. Но это сильно все усложняет.

В идеале хотелось бы получить нечто вроде веток в git.
Одна ветка - текущая версия, а вторая новая. И в зависимости от версии файла выбирать скрипты и модули из нужной ветки.

Также и сериализатор. Но для него нужен будет некий адаптер, который будет из текущей версии делать новую.

В общем хотелось бы узнать, кто как решает такую задачу.
Может есть какие-то более правильные варианты?

Comment: Ну надо выбрать наверно какой-то транспорт/хранения/версирования: svn,git итд. Потом поставить CI по вкусу, или скрипты по вкусу, завести второй репозиторий где будет продакшн, и скриптами по удовлетворительному результату копировать в продакшн и в последствии коммитить куда нужно далее.. в выходной общедоступный git например.. схема примерно такая

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял ничего...

Comment: На уровне CI разбирать ветки с выходными данными, в каждой ветке (trunk) живёт своя версия данных и соответственно свои обработчики. Потом обработанные стандартизируемые данные кидаете в выходной репозиторий, откуда происходит импорт в бд. Благодаря версирования удобно будет разбить весь поток данных на состовляющие в соответствии с типом данных.

Comment: Если незнакома аббревиатура CI, то [читать тут](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Непрерывная_интеграция)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то суть идеи в том, что бы взять именно git (к примеру) и использовать его средства разделения версий на ходу? Ну вот такое в голове и крутилось, но как-то не было уверенности, что подход верный.

Comment: На самом деле в данном случае будет более удобен SVN, там хуки погибче настраиваются и нет пересечения транков - если их изначально верно заводить. В git с транками будет каша, это конечно личное имхо.